# Цикл по многомерному объекту JavaScript

Tags: javascript, объекты, for, foreach

Есть задача:

```
const get = (obj, path) => {

};

console.log(get({ a: 1 }, "a"));// === 1 true
console.log(get({ a: { b: 1 } }, "a.b")); // === 1 true
console.log(get({ a: { b: 1 } }, "a.c")); //  === undefined
console.log(get({ a: { b: { c: 1 } } }, "a.c.b") ); // === null
console.log(get({ a: { b: { c: 1 } } }, "a.b.c") ); // === true
```

Нужно написать функцию get, которая будет принимать объект и путь и в случае если все передано верно возвращать true, иначе false, если такого пути нет undefined, а если в путь передан не в той последовательности - null. Проблема в том, что здесь вложенные друг в друга объекты, если их определенное количество (напр. 3), то я эту задачу решила вложенными циклами (хоть громоздко,но работает), но эта функция должна работать с любым уровнем вложенных объектов. Спасибо!

Comment: "в путь передан не в той последовательности" - ?? "я эту задачу решила" - где?

Comment: На собеседовании решила. Здесь вопрос не в том, как и где я ее решила, а в том, что мое решение не совсем точное и гибкое. Нужна функция которая работает над объектом с ЛЮБОЙ вложенностью, а не только с 2-мя или 3-мя объектами.

Comment: Почему бы Вам сначала не попробовать сделать это самой?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что я не попробовала?

Comment: Я взял это с того, что между фигурными скобками функции `get` ничего нет.

Comment: интересно а длина всегда совпадает со вложенностью объекта?

Comment: @Alexandr Это не имеет значения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может можно и проще как то:

```js
const get = (obj, path) => {

 path = path.split('.');

 let curObj = obj;
 let pathDump = ''
 for ( let i = 0 ; i < path.length ; i++){
 
   let key  = Object.keys(curObj)[0]
   pathDump += key;
   curObj = curObj[key]; 
   
 }

 return pathDump == path.join('') || (path.every(i => pathDump.includes(i)) ? null : undefined)
};


console.log('res:' , get({ a: 1 }, "a"));// === 1 true
console.log('res:' , get({ a: { b: 1 } }, "a.b")); // === 1 true
console.log('res:' , get({ a: { b: 1 } }, "a.c")); //  === undefined
console.log('res:' , get({ a: { b: { c: 1 } } }, "a.c.b") ); // === null
console.log('res:' , get({ a: { b: { c: 1 } } }, "a.b.c") ); // === true
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь подумаю как с null проверить, это оказалось сложнее, чем я думала

Comment: @NataliaChufistova переделал немного, теперь как надо работает

Comment: Спасибо еще раз! С null я так и не додумалась.